# How to sort $nodes after executing an EntityFieldQuery

Tags: database

Am using Drupal 7 and EFQs. After executing the query and geting all the nodes listed in a custom module, I need to sort them on node title field.

I can use usort and other php functions but my problem is the field am sorting on can't seem to get it from `$nodes`. How can I achieve this? Nothing that I must sort after the EFQ execution therefore I can't use `fieldOrderBy`.

The thing is, am callling 2 EFQs with different fields and merging them. That is why I need to sort them after -> execute

Below is the code after the EFQ execution:

```
    $nidsMall = array_keys($resultMall['node']);
    $nidsStore = array_keys($resultStore['node']);

    $nodesStore = entity_load('node', $nidsStore);
    $nodesMall = entity_load('node', $nidsMall);

    $nodes = (object) array_merge((array) $nodesStore, (array) $nodesMall);
```

I'm making sure that both EFQs return the wanted results.

I need to sort $nodes on node title or any other field. (both content types mall and store have that field, naturally)

Appreciate any help given.

Thanks

Comment: You can do it before the `->execute();` line, as the solution in the above link does it.

Comment: The thing is, am callling 2 EFQs with different fields and merging them. That is why I need to sort them after -> execute

Comment: This is not a duplicate since my question isn't about sorting in EFQ (I know how EFQ sorting works), it's sorting after EFQ execution

Comment: Sorry for getting this closed, I wasn't aware at the time that you were executing two separate EFQ's I've voted to re-open. If you're combining them into an array use one of the [PHP array sorts](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp). If this won't do, then you need to explain what exactly are you sorting by.

Comment: `is the field am sorting on can't seem to get it from $nodes`. The answer to your question is probably going to end up being not to use EFQ and instead use [static query](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries) or [dynamic query](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries) where you have the ability to join any table you like.

Comment: Yeah, it seems there's no way around it. You may be right, I'll see what I can do, thanks mate

Comment: I usually need to do the following after using EFQ: 1) check that i got results in `$results['node']` 2) `$keys = array_keys($results['node']);` to pull out node ids 3) `$nodes = node_load_multiple($keys);` to actually load the full nodes. Are you actually getting/loading the full node entities or does `$nodes` directly from EFQ? I think this is still too unclear about what you're doing and you should provide more code.

Comment: I edited my question to show the code

Comment: I see you're casting your `$nodes` array to an object, which is probably why PHP sort functions won't work. Try removing the cast and use `usort` with a string comparator function. `strcmp` can compare strings alphabetically for a start. Hope this helps!